# Is window.location a non-blocking operation?

Tags: javascript

While working on a defect I came across window.location behavior which was different from my understanding. Until this issue, I believed the assigning a value to **window.location** would block other operations and proceed with redirection.

```
// Try to answer the questions before you run this script on JSFiddle.
// 1. Which site is going to load as a result of redirect method - apple.com or mashable.com?
// 2. Will the console log 'script added' print in console?
function redirect(url) {
  var el = document.createElement('script');
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var content = "window.location.href='"+url+"'";

  el.innerHTML = content;

  head.appendChild(el);
}

console.log('adding scripts');
redirect('http://apple.com');
redirect('http://mashable.com');
console.log('script added');
```

I tried to look for documentation that explains this behavior but couldn't find any. Any documentation or article explaining the window.location in detail will be useful.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#source-browsing-context)? I don't envy you.

Comment: HTML5 does not require the `window.location` attribute assignment operation to be blocking. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface

Comment: So what 2 redirects are supposed to do?

Comment: If you click a link, can you still click another link before the browser loads the page? ... there's your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Javascript, setting `window.location.href` is generally a non-blocking operation.**

You can still run Javascript operations while the DNS is resolving for the new page. Thus, if you change `location.href` before this is done, you're starting the process over.

You can read how `window.location` (specifically `window.location.assign`) is expected to perform in Javascript at **[WHATWG: Living HTML - HTML Standard.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-location-assign)**

When the `window.location` object is set, the web browser initiates either the **[`Location-object navigate`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#location-object-setter-navigate)** or the **[`Location-object-setter navigate`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#location-object-setter-navigate)** subroutines.

Comment: Thanks @NextLocal. I was not looking for solution. My intent is to learn where is it documented that window.location.href is a non-blocking operation.

Comment: Where do the quotes in the answer come from?

Comment: Could you elaborate what your code sample exactly does? If it's "blocking" - then what is the purpose of the second redirect call?

Comment: @Moorthy: why should it be stated like that anywhere? It's a variable assignment.

Comment: @zerkms the purpose of the second redirect call is just to show that it doesn't get run :)

Comment: If all you need is to ensure a function should be able to run once then your implementation is awful. Just create a flag `was_invoked` and check if it's `true`, without any ugly `document.write`

Comment: "The reason this operation is non-blocking is because you can still run Javascript operations while the DNS is resolving for the new page" --- that's not the reason. Those are consequences.

Comment: @zerkms agreed - removed example. Moorthy my answer was updated and hopefully provides some insight

Comment: If its blocking then the second redirect call should not work. But its not. My question is where is it documented, as Oriol asked, _where do the quotes in the answer come from_.  @NextLocal the second redirect call does work which is the reason I am  here. If you drop the code in JSFiddle you could see the second redirect is what that works.